# What is the right port and IP adress for Tor proxy on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, proxy

I would like to set up a proxy that routes my traffic through Tor and then connect to my VPN. I have already found a few threads here but with conflicting answers.
In the control panel I can set up a proxy but what is the IP and port for Tor? The IP should be 127.0.0.1 right? But what is the Port is it either 9150 or 9050?

Do I have the tor browser running in the background to achieve the goal of routing my traffic through Tor?

Hopefully someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. By **default** it's 9050, but since Windows 7 SP1 and forth Microsoft looks like to mess up things intentionally: some system services are taking 9050 and they are the system ones or they are *coming back by themselves* after an update. So - as I'm doing it - I'm setting a port explicitly, like 9999 or 19999 e.t.c., so it will not be taken.
2. Tor browser has absolutely **nothing** to do about the traffic routing, so you need to use virtualization or a physical router to do so

Comment: But what do I have to put in the proxy settings then? And is a proxy not designed to put my traffic through the proxy (Tor in this case) ?

Comment: Proxy is designed to put your traffic through **by your explicit request** - so you need to use Socks5**s** and port like 9999. A Transparent proxy is *actually* a router, it's not a proxy - it works with the help of firewall. In your browser you're setting SOCKS proxy, but be warned about proxy bypassing fingerprinting